# i am having a problem with not in function in mysql, here is the query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
delete from emploee_id where id not in(select max(id) from emploee_id group by name,dept,salary,experience);
```

while running this query the error is showing as like this

> "Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'emploee_id' for
> update in FROM clause"

please someone help me out here

Answer (score 0):

You could do a JOIN to a temp table instead

```
delete e 
from emploee_id e
left join
(
  select select max(id) as id
  from emploee_id 
  group by name, dept, salary, experience
) tmp on tmp.id = e.id
where tmp.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not use the same table in a subquery. Try to use
**SET @variable_name = select max(id) from emploee_id group by name,dept,salary,experience** as a separate query and set its value in variable.
Then use that value in **delete query delete from emploee_id where id=@variable_name**

Comment: The subquery doesn't necessarily return only one row, so assigning it to a scalar variable won't work in most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
"delete from emploee_id where id not in(select max(id) from emploee_id group by name,dept,salary,experience); "
```

there's no target actually, there should be a where clause in that select statement
example

```
"delete from emploee_id where id not in(select max(id) from emploee_id **where** group by name,dept,salary,experience); "
```

i really think you look at the sql selected code again and be sure of what you're trying to query